# Resources/Materials for Microsoft CA role/PKI

Tags: windows, server, certificate, ca

Does SO have some recommended readings for Microsoft's CA role, Certificates, and PKI? My company is preparing to replacing our two domain controllers (hardware replacement and going from 2012 R2 to Server 2022 so an in place upgrade isn't really feasible) and one of them has our local CA.

Our current CA isn't doing all that much, just:

Directory Email Replication

Kerberos Authentication

Domain Controller Authentication

NPS

One instance of Windows Server Solutions Computer Certificate Template which I am not 100% certain of its function

In theory it's also plugged into our Exchange server but I am not seeing any active issued certificates for it

We have around 35 workstations and 9-10 instances of Windows Server so, in my mind, simply starting a new CA on the new DC (or other server instance) is not out of the realm of possibilities, but I would like to learn some more about CA's and PKI. I understand the basic function (CA is a trusted issuer of certificates, issues certificates to other machines for various purposes, PKI is the creation of a public and private key pair in which the certificate has the public key for the device it was issued to) but I would like to understand more about the different certificate templates and the setup/migration of the Microsoft CA role.